# html injection question

Tags: asp.net

Using FreeTextBox, I'm capturing HTML-formatted text. The purpose is to allow a website owner to update their web page content on a few pages. I have the system completed except for knowing what to do with the resultant HTML markup.

After the page editor completes their work, I can get the output from FreeTextBox, in html format, like so: `<font color="#000080"><b>This is some text.</b></font>`

I tried storing it as escaped markup in web.config, but that didn't work since it kept hosing the tags even after I changed them to escaped characters, like so: `&lt;font color=&quot;#000080&quot;&gt;`

The reason I wanted to store this kind of string as a key in web.config is that I could successfully store a static string, set a lebel's value to it, and successfully render the text. But when I try to escape it, it gets reformatted in web.config by .Net somehow.

So I escaped all the characters, encoded them as Base64 and stored that. Then on page_load, I tried to decode it, but it just shows up as text, with all the html tags showing as well - it doesn't get rendered. I know a million people use this control, but I'm damned if I can figure out how to do it right.

So here's my question: how can I inject the saved HTML into an edited page so it shows up in browsers like the editor wants it to look?

Comment: Do you have an example of how you are displaying the saved HTML on a page?  If you have a string containing HTML tags, throwing it in a label will output the tags and cause the browser to render them (provided they are actually tags, and not &lt;, but Server.HtmlDecode can be used to deal with that).

Answer (score 0):

Try `Server.HtmlDecode` to output the HTML to the screen.
As a side note, I prefer to use CKEditor for html-formatted input. I found it is the better option among all options (FreeTextBox, TinyMCE, anything else?) and it has got completely rewritten and faster in the version 3.0!

Comment: You're asking me to "try" your solution. I must admit to a certain skepticism about your answer when it also includes a plug for a program that is for sale. Furthermore, I certainly would not be posting on Stack Overflow if I had not already tried that.

Comment: Sorry for the "try". I just wasn't completely sure to use the verb "Use". Regarding the program, I am not in any way affiliated to that, as you might be wondering. This is just something I use, like and thought you might want to check out. And it has an open source license as well.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone comes here for the answer, here's one way to do it.

I had initial problems with web.config changing some of the HTML tags upon storage, so we use B64 encoding (may not be necessary). Store the saved html markup to an AppSettings key in web.config as Base64 encoding, using this for your setting update function. Add error checking and whatever else you need it to do:

```
'create configuration object
Dim cfg As Configuration
cfg = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~")
'get reference to appsettings("HTMLstring")
Dim HTMLString As KeyValueConfigurationElement = _
CType(cfg.AppSettings.Settings("HTMLstring"), KeyValueConfigurationElement)

'get text entered by user and marked up with HTML tags from FTB1, then
'encode as Base64 so we can store it as XML-safe string in web.config
Dim b64String As String = Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(FTB1.Text))

'save new value into web.config
If Not HTMLString Is Nothing Then
    HTMLString.Value = b64String
    cfg.Save()
End If
```

Next, add a Literal control to the aspx markup:

```
<asp:Literal id="charHTML" runat="server"/>
```

To add the saved HTML to the post-edited page, do the following in Page_Load:

```
'this string of HTML code is stored in web.config as Base64 to preserve XML-unsafe characters that come from FreeTextBox.
Dim injectedHTML As String = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(AppSettings("HTMLstring")))

'the literal control will directly inject this HTML instead of encoding it
charHTML.Mode = LiteralMode.PassThrough
'set the value
charHTML.Text = injectedHTML
```

Hope this helps. sF